# Update post's custom fields after workflow step approved or rejected in gravity flow

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms

I am making a functionality in which I want to **Update the Project Status ** every time the Gravity Forms are submitted by the users on a single project.

Like if one user sent a payment request then the post status will be updated with " Payment Request sent" in project status custom field.

And When an Approval request is sent then if Workflow Step is Approved by the end user the Project status will be updated.

I really need help with this.
Many Hopes from this forum.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. Please note that 3rd party plugins, such as Gravity Forms, are considered off-topic here on WPSE. Should you have any questions regarding the setup, usage or customization of such plugin, please contact the author for support or see the documentation the author has provided.

Comment: This was not the answer to my problem. If documentation was that helpful this website would never be made.

Comment: Yes, I understand. It's just that third party plugins require very specific knowledge and understanding of their inner workings for someone to be able to give any insight or advice how to work with them. As WPSE's focus is on the WordPress core and development directly related to it, you might have hard time recieving quality answers within reasonable timeframe here. You might want to consider asking the same question on StackOverflow as your question could better reach someone who knows Gravity Forms really well.

Comment: ok Thanks you for the information.